# Exported variable 'router' has or is using name 'Router' from external module but cannot be named

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, module

In the common construct of defining nested routers in multiple files when exporting a router directly using Typescript 2 and the `@types/express@4.0.35` definition following code throws

```
error TS4023: Exported variable 'router' has or is using name 'Router' from external module 
         "[...]/node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index" but cannot be named.
```

Example taken from [basarat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37175234/4068027)

```
import * as express from "express";

// import sub-routers
import * as adminRouter from "./admin/admin";
import * as productRouter from "./products/products";

let router = express.Router();

// mount express paths, any addition middleware can be added as well.
// ex. router.use('/pathway', middleware_function, sub-router);

router.use('/products', productRouter);
router.use('/admin', adminRouter);

// Export the router
export = router;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is to explicitly annotate the router variable ([TypeScript/issues/5711#issuecomment-161194656](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5711#issuecomment-161194656)).

Following code will work (note the `let router: express.Router = express.Router()`)

```
import * as express from "express";

import * as adminRouter from "./admin/admin";
import * as productRouter from "./products/products";

let router: express.Router = express.Router();

router.use('/products', productRouter);
router.use('/admin', adminRouter);

// Export the router
export = router;
```

Comment: what you have in your `productRouter`, I just tried to `import router from "../app"

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

export = router;` and it doesn't work