# typescript express get does not work in separate files

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm currently converting my node code to node-ts to help our development flow for someone that is going to help out.

I tried using this information ([typescript node.js express routes separated files best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167602/typescript-node-js-express-routes-separated-files-best-practices)) initially but that didn't work, so as of right now I have this below

In my `index.ts` I have this on the bottom

```
import Auth from "./routes/Auth";
app.use('/auth', Auth.Routing());

export = app;
```

Then in my `./routes/Auth.ts` I have this

```
const Routing = function() {
    app.get('/session', User.session);

    return app;
}

export = { Routing };
```

When I try to access `/auth/session` all it returns is `index_1.default.get`.

Using the link above, I attempted to use `const router = express.Router();` and then `export = router` and what not but was unable to get it to work for that either with the same error.

Comment: Try to remove `=`, i.e.: `export app`, and `export { Routing }`

Comment: It still returns the same error, though I had to use `export { app }` instead.