# How to use express router in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to convert an old project in typescript and having some issue on routing. It does not seems to recognize the sub file routing as mentioned on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167602/typescript-node-js-express-routes-separated-files-best-practices)

**app.ts**

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();

import * as contentRouter from "./routes/content";
import * as blogRouter from "./routes/blog";

let router: express.Router = express.Router();

// All routing here
router.use("/content", contentRouter);
router.use("/blog", blogRouter);

// Export the router
export = router;
```

**./routes/content.ts**

```
import router from "../app"

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

export default router
```

[image]

Comment: `import * as contentRouter from` is wrong; it's the default export, so should just be `import contentRouter from`.

Comment: Doing that throw another error on content.ts with message `TypeError: app_1.default.get is not a function`

Comment: Wait why are you exporting the router from app.ts? The routes/*.ts files should create and export their own routers to plug into the main one.

Comment: Do you mean, I should use `import { Router } from "express";
let router = Router();` on all my sub-routes ?

Comment: Yes, see e.g. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router for how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Yup, got it working!